# Operation on a variable and constant giving different result in c

Tags: c, calculation, pow, modulo

A simple calculation: 3^20%15. 
The answer, according to a calculator, is 6.

The following code generates answer 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
        int i = 20;
        printf("%d\n", ((int)pow(3,20)%15));
        return 0;
}
```

If I replace `20` in the `printf` statement with the variable `i`, it gives `-8` as output.

Assuming that the calculator is correct (or not?), what is the problem in the program?

Comment: The numerical limits of integers are usually addressed in the first chapters of any C programming book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `pow(3,20)` can't fit in an `int` on your platform (or mine for that matter). Because of that, you're experiencing unexpected results.

Changing to a larger integer type such as `long long` will do the job.

Moreover, `pow` works with floating-point numbers which aren't represented exactly in memory (look that up). During conversion to an integer, that can cause certain errors. For example, for `printf("%fl\n", (pow(3,20)));` I get `3486784401.000000l` which is not a precise integer value.

Comment: Additionally, note that poor implementations of `pow` may return inaccurate results for `pow(3, 20)`. They may return 3486784400.999999523162841796875 instead of 3486784401, which would cause the conversion to `int` to produce 3486784400 (before final conversion to 32-bit).

Comment: Answers to this question should also address why there is a difference between `pow(3, 20)` and `pow(3, i)`, as the question asked.

Comment: Unfortunately, the new statements in this answer about floating-point are not correct. Each floating-point object that is not a NaN represents one number exactly. The rounding errors in floating-point operations occur during operations, not in numbers. And the error I cautioned about occurs in poor implementations of `pow`, not in conversion to an integer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't think there is a difference between `pow(3, 20)` and `pow(3, i)`. The problem the OP is seeing comes from the fact that `int` can't hold such a large value. That's about that. Please post an answer that is more technically correct, this is as far as I can go.

Comment: Likely the compiler evaluated `pow(3, 20)` at compile time and `pow(3, i)` at run time. Sometimes the arithmetic used by a compiler at compile time differs from the arithmetic used at run time.

Answer (score 1):

What likely happened here is:

- In your C implementation, `int` is 32 bits, with a minimum of −2,147,483,648 and a maximum of 2,147,483,647.
- The result of `pow(3, 20)` is 3486784401. (See note 1 below.)
- 3486784401 is too large for an `int`, so there is an overflow. In case of integer overflow, the C standard permits an implementation to do anything.
- In `(int) pow(3, 20)`, the conversion to `int` may have been computed at a compile time by producing the maximum, 2,147,483,647. Then the remainder of that divided by 15 is 7.
- In `(int) pow(3, i)`, the conversion to `int` may have been computed at run time by producing the minimum, −2,147,483,648. (Some processors produce such a result for integer overflows.) Then the remainder of that divided by 15 is −8.

In summary:

- Your code overflows, so the C standard does not define the behavior.
- The compiler likely behaves differently for `pow(3, 20)` and `pow(3, i)` because it evaluates the former at compile time and the latter at execution time.

## Note

1. Good implementations of `pow` return exactly 3486784401 for `pow(3, 20)`. Unfortunately, poor implementations may return inaccurate values such as 3486784401.000000476837158203125 or 3486784400.999999523162841796875.